# Webservice Connection Refused Exception while trying to access WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn webservices .I have generated a client using wsimport in my local machine . When i set the workspace in RAD and run the application im getting below exception, i have searched in google for similar issues but i couldnt find solution, so it would really help me if someone can shed some light on this issue so that i can move forward with learning weservices. When i use the WSDL url in browser, im able to access it without issues.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://www.webservicex.com/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL. It failed with: 
Got Connection refused: connect while opening stream from http://www.webservicex.com/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:185)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:167)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:132)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:270)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:233)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:113)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:88)
at net.webservicex.GeoIPService.<init>(GeoIPService.java:39)
at net.webservicex.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

My Code is below :

```
package net.webservicex;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GeoIPService obj = new GeoIPService();

        GeoIPServiceSoap obj1 = obj.getGeoIPServiceSoap();

        GeoIP obj3 = new GeoIP();

        obj3 = obj1.getGeoIP("www.google.com");

        System.out.println(obj3.getIP());
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.webservicex.com/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL the connection is refused. It means the WSDL is not there. Ask the developers of the WSDL to give you the right URL to access the service. It seems like either they might be publishing somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Namphibian,
WSDL is present . i am able to access the link thru chrome. Its not working in RAD. that is my problem.please advise..